# No Color Frames since Updating to Jacobi Release 1.8

Tags: google-project-tango

Since I have updated to the Jacobi C API (Release 1.8 and later) I do not receive any color frames anymore, i.e., more specifically, I successfully register a callback function `__onFrameAvailable()`, using

```
if( TANGO_SUCCESS != TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable(
         TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR, NULL, __onFrameAvailable) )
{
  LOG_ERROR("TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable() failed.");
  return FALSE;
}
else
{
  LOG_INFO("TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable() successful.");
} // if
```

but that function is never ever called. Even if I set the configuration paramater `config_enable_color_camera` to TRUE, using

```
if( TANGO_SUCCESS != TangoConfig_setBool(configE, "config_enable_color_camera", TRUE) )
{
  LOG_ERROR("TangoConfig_setBool(config_enable_color_camera=true) failed.");
  return FALSE;
} // if
else
{
  LOG_INFO("TangoConfig_setBool(config_enable_color_camera=true) successful.");
} // if
```

this has no effect.

However, when I uninstall the Project Tango Core and revert to the factory settings, function `__onFrameAvailable()` is called. I did not have this problem with the Ito Release 1.7...

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This is indeed a bug which was caused due to a change in Graphic binder buffer, in Kalman release. I have already reported this bug internally and we are working to resolve this issue asap. I will let you know once there is an update.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When can we expect the update? Currently, my work is stuck as I cannot revert to the Jacobi Release...