# TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable appears to be broken

Tags: google-project-tango

Until the Kalman release, which I am still running, I could capture color camera images via a call on TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable.  This call still returns OK, but the provided callback function is never called, for either camera.  I have forcibly removed and reinstalled the project tango core. I would check against reference code, but according to GitHub, there isn't a single call to this function in the C samples.  I've walked this enough to be reasonably sure it ain't me.  The callback simply never occurs.  It used to.  It needs to.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug confirmed by the dev team in a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347730/no-color-frames-since-updating-to-jacobi-release-1-8)

I am sure they will fix it soon.

Comment: Confirmed third hand maybe - as always, crickets with respect to any stream of actual information from the source.